# sleep command using screen command is not displayed in ps

Tags: scripting, gnu-screen, ps

I'm running the sleep command in terminal using screen and in detached mode.
Once the screen immediately returns, I'm running `ps` command to verify the sleep is running.

```
$ screen -d -m 'sleep 2m'
[raj@localhost ~]$ ps
PID TTY          TIME CMD
22795 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
22869 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

But the command didn't show sleep. What is that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: why would you want to run `sleep` through a detached `screen` ? couldn’t you just run it as `sleep 2m &` directly from your shell ? besides, `ps` alone shows only processes belonging to your terminal window, while whatever you run through `screen` will belong to a different virtual terminal

Comment: @LL3 - I'm doing it as a poc to run a command from remote machine using screen and detach from screen. I have tried using `ps -a | grep sleep` still it is not showing any new process running sleep.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was confusing to me initially as well. I then re-read the local `screen` man page for the SYNOPSIS -- the [online man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen) does not give a synopsis) -- and noticed that it said:

> ```
> screen [ -options ] [ cmd [ args ] ]
> ```

... which led me to believe that it wanted to see the `cmd` and `args` as independent arguments.

Since you gave that first argument as a quoted value -- '`sleep 2m`' -- it tried to execute a command named (exactly) '`sleep 2m`', as opposed to what you *really* wanted, which was `sleep` with its own argument of `2m`. The `screen` command exited successfully (in my testing), but it did *not* successfully execute your command.

Use, instead:

```
screen -d -m sleep 2m
```

Instead of `ps`, which will only show processes associated with the current terminal (of which the SCREEN and related processes are *not*), use:

```
ps x
```

which will show it:

```
$ ps x
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 # ...
 7514 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
 7761 ?        Ss     0:00 SCREEN -d -m sleep 2m
 7762 pts/2    Ss+    0:00 sleep 2m
 7880 pts/1    R+     0:00 ps x
 # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Would using `nohup` suffice? It will show in `ps` where as running it in screen may make the process hidden within the screen process.

An example of this would be from bash..

```
nohup your-command &
```

If you want to exit this terminal session you may want to use an `at` job command..

```
at now + 1 minute

nohup your-command &

(ctrl-d)
```

Comment: (1) This is confusing.  You talk about a script and redirecting the standard output, neither of which is in the question.  On the other hand, the question features a `sleep` command, which your answer doesn’t mention. (2) Can you explain why you believe that `nohup` will help?  Do you believe that some process (e.g., `sleep`) is getting a hangup signal? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) Using `nohup` would probably not *suffice.* [Jeff’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511443/80216#511461) presents two reasons why the user is not seeing the result they’re expecting. Adding `nohup` might be necessary *also,* but, by itself, it’s not likely to be enough.

Comment: I’ve made it more clear. Was just pasting a real life example and hadn’t considered the confusion. Sorry.